# Can I obtain the pure state corresponding to a density matrix from its main diagonal?

Tags: density-matrix

Suppose we have a bipartite pure state as follows:

$$|\psi\rangle=a_1|00\rangle+a_2|01\rangle+a_3|10\rangle+a_4|11\rangle\,.$$

Then, the density matrix is as follows:

$$|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a_1^2 & a_1 a_2 & a_1 a_3 & a_1 a_4 \\
 a_1 a_2 & a_2^2 & a_2 a_3 & a_2 a_4 \\
 a_1 a_3 & a_2 a_3 & a_3^2 & a_3 a_4 \\
 a_1 a_4 & a_2 a_4 & a_3 a_4 & a_4^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\,.$$

Now, suppose I have the density matrix of the pure state and don't have the state. Can I obtain the pure state using the main diagonal of the density matrix?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/26964/55

Comment: The title does not match the question - it asks the opposite!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: in writing out your density matrix, you're forgetting that the amplitudes can be complex. So the diagonal elements are things like $|a_1|^2$. You can never determine the complex phase of these values from just the diagonal elements.

Comment: Even if you restrict to real density matrices the $\pm 1$ phase cannot be determined.